# How to Take Care of 3-Way Pan/Tilt Tripod Head

Tags: equipment-recommendation, tripod, tripod-heads

I have a [Manfrotto 808RC4 3-Way Pan/Tilt Head with RC4 Quick Release](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/445434-REG/Manfrotto_808RC4_808RC4_3_Way_Pan_Tilt_Head.html)

However, I'm not sure how to take care of it to prolong its life. Does anybody know how I would do so? For example, do I add grease to it after each use? Or these tripod heads are made to last without maintenance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you expose it to very harsh conditions (fine sand or saltwater, for example), it is probably sufficient to keep in in a dust-proof bag when not in use.

Comment: Manfrotto equipment is very sturdy and solid. Unless you inadvertently damaged it yourself I would expect it to last at least for your lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally bought a padded carrying case for my Manfrotto tripod. Thought this is a good idea since it:

- enables me to easily carry the tripod around
- protects the tripod when I go around places
- prevents dust from covering the tripod when not in use
- **prevents dust from sticking to the grease in the tripod head (very important)**

I now also give the tripod a wipe down after each use.